# Initialize MySQL database as non-root and run SQL server for testing

Tags: linux, debian, mysql, privileges, temporary-files

I want to do some MySQL-specific testing and need to run a fresh MySQL database as non-root user. I am using Debian Linux and expect one could start the `mysql_install_db` and other commands as normal user with the right options and writable locations.

1. Does this work?
2. How to do it?

I don't want to download software from the MySQL website. Instead I want to use the executables provided by the already installed OS packages. The reasoning is this:

1. The software is already installed--installing new software from the net is pointless, slow, might fail, possibly a security risk etc. To my knowledge KDE is doing something similar for its data storage.
2. If it does eventually work I want to wrap the test in a portable script that runs on any computer where `mysql_install_db` etc. are available.

I searched the web for tutorials/hints but only found loads of descriptions on how to install the software from scratch. With information from what I had read I then tried this:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/mysql/
mkdir ~/tmp/mysql/mysql/
mkdir ~/tmp/mysql/sql_data/

mysql_install_db \
    --defaults-file=my.cnf
    --user=daniel
    --basedir=/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/mysql/
    --datadir=/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/sql_data/
    --socket=/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/socket
```

But it complains:

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults

The following directories were searched:

   /home/daniel/tmp/mysql/mysql//bin
   /home/daniel/tmp/mysql/mysql//extra
```

**UPDATE:** I still didn't find a solution to limiting the output to error messages. I get many lines with the tag `[Note]` but didn't find an argument to set debug output level.

Comment: I found a source for my belief in the Akonadi FAQ under [Do I need a running MySQL server?](https://techbase.kde.org/KDE_PIM/Akonadi#Do_I_need_a_running_MySQL_server.3F) and probably the relevant source code in [src/server/storage/dbconfigmysql.cpp](https://quickgit.kde.org/?p=akonadi.git&a=blob&h=a604648919f5ce68d44d813328dff8c619641c1c&hb=35d02744faced9123e444ece771aaff94276f2a2&f=src%2Fserver%2Fstorage%2Fdbconfigmysql.cpp)

Comment: What's in `/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/mysql/bin` at the beginning of this process?  Anything?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: The directories `bin` and `extra` don't exist. I updated my question to reflect which directories I created. As you see I created them from scratch. They're empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar calls in the Akonadi code and started to build the commands from scratch while consulting the respective help texts. It looks like I just included useless/counterproductive options before. This did now work for me:

```
mysql_install_db                    \
  --defaults-file=/dev/null         \ # don't user my.cnf in /etc/ or ~/
  --datadir=/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/ \ # use given directory for data
  --force                             # make mysqld work without /usr/bin/resolveip
```

I seem to need only 1 directory for data. Setting `basedir` only works if you provide a complete MySQL installation.

After this I could run the MySQL server:

```
mysqld                              \
  --defaults-file=/dev/null         \ # as above
  --datadir=/home/daniel/tmp/mysql/ \ # as above
  --socket=/home/daniel/tmp/socket  \ # use writable socket
  --skip-networking                   # for my purposes: only socket connections
```