# mysql - how-to non-root server startup on linux (redhat)

Tags: linux, mysql

I have installed mysql 5.7 (untar-ed the compressed binary) on a RedHat 6 (64 bit) machine on which I do not have root access.

I am following [this](https://dzone.com/articles/setting-up-mysql-without-root-access) tutorial to start the sql server and initialize the database but I am getting errors. The solution posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1058423/initialize-mysql-database-as-non-root-and-run-sql-server-for-testing) also gives errors and it is recommended not to use `mysql_install_db` anymore as its deprecated.

**What I have done so far**: I have untar-ed the binary into the directory `/home/username/mysql/` (stored in the variable `$MYSQL_HOME`) and in there created a `data/` and `log/` folder. I also create two files `my.ini` and `my.cnf`

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
user=mysqluser
```

**my.ini**

```
export BASE_DIR=$MYSQL_HOME
export DATADIR=$BASE_DIR/data
```

From `$MYSQL_HOME/mysql-install-folder/bin` I run

```
./mysqld --user=mysqluser 
    --datadir=$DATADIR 
    --basedir=$MYSQL_HOME 
    --log-error=$MYSQL_HOME/log/mysql.err 
    --pid-file=$MYSQL_HOME/mysql.pid 
    --socket=$MYSQL_HOME/socket 
    --port=3306 
    --initialize
```

However I get this error

```
 323$ ./mysqld --user=quad --datadir=$DATADIR --basedir=$MYSQL_HOME --log-error=$MYSQL_HOME/log/mysql.err --pid-file=$MYSQL_HOME/mysql.pid --socket=$MYSQL_HOME/socket --port=3306 --initialize
2018-03-26T18:12:22.795302Z 0 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'mysqluser' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

2018-03-26T18:12:22.795338Z 0 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'mysqluser' because the user was set to 'mysql' earlier on the command line

2018-03-26T18:12:22.795352Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-03-26T18:12:22.795410Z 0 [ERROR] Can't find error-message file '/home/username/mysql/share/errmsg.sys'. Check error-message file location and 'lc-messages-dir' configuration directive.
2018-03-26T18:12:22.797158Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2018-03-26T18:12:22.797183Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

First of all I dont get why it doesnt override the username `mysql` and then the error about the error message file is quite cryptic to me.

### **EDIT**

I followed the instructions [here](http://www.martijn-onderwater.nl/2010/11/23/installing-mysql-on-linux-without-root-privileges/), now I have this config file in `/home/username/mysql`:

**my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock
basedir=[Base MySQL Directory]
datadir=[Base MySQL Directory]/data
log-error=[Base MySQL Directory]/data/mysql.err
pid-file=[Base MySQL Directory]/mysql.pid
user=username

[client]
port=3306
socket=[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock
user=username

[mysqladmin]
socket=[Base MySQL Directory]/thesock
user=username
```

When I setup the server with

```
./mysqld --defaults-file=$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf&
```

it shows me I guess a process id

```
[2] 2281405
```

but when I try to start the client with

```
./mysql --defaults-file=/home/SHD_xnqu/mysql/my.cnf
```

it throws the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Unknown error 1045
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: FYI.... As per **6.1.5 How to Run MySQL as a Normal User**.... "[*On Linux, for installations performed using a MySQL repository, RPM packages, or Debian packages, the MySQL server mysqld should be started by the local mysql operating system user. Starting by another operating system user is not supported by the init scripts that are included as part of the installation.*"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/changing-mysql-user.html)

Comment: Maybe you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950722/how-to-overcome-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-odbclocalhost-u